# how to select distinct value in self inner join mysql query?

Tags: mysql

This mysql query selects max value from reviews but insId is duplicate but i want to get with out duplicate insId.

```
SELECT reviews.id, reviews_max.insId, reviews_max.maxAvgRating
FROM 
(
    SELECT insId, MAX(avgRating) AS maxAvgRating
    FROM reviews
    WHERE status = '1'
    GROUP BY insId
) AS reviews_max 
INNER JOIN reviews
    ON reviews.insId = reviews_max.insId AND
       reviews.avgRating = reviews_max.maxAvgRating
```

Comment: Please include some sample data to better explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do it without the subselect like this?

```
SELECT MAX(reviews.id) as id, MAX(reviews.insId), MAX(reviews.avgRating) AS maxAvgRating
FROM reviews
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY reviews.id, reviews.insId
```

If you like to you can still duplicate id as insId but that value should already be in the id field.

I created a quick example using SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b6421/2/0